# Facebook og:title fetched only in recent activities and not in the wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook open graph to make a custom action like this:

UserName is tagging a Post with MyApp.

It works well, but I have only one problem:

In my recent activities I have:
Bed77 is tagging a Red Gorgeous Post with MyApp.

and in my wall I have:
Bed77 is tagging a Post with MyApp.

"*Red Gorgeous Post*" is the og:title that I have set for that object in my page.

Why it's fetched only in recent activities and not in the wall?
It's an automatic facebook decision?

Explained with one image:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: i have a side question, how do you get the post to show up on timeline as well? I can only get to show in the "Recent Activities" box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the locations of *object-type* and *object-title* are determined by Facebook in what are called 'Timeline Units'.

In your example, "red gorgeous POST" (the title) is displayed below the header ("Duccio is tagging a POST with PostBlogger").

Recent Activity has a different format that is more compact.

In OG Aggregation Units you have some control over the display of objects and their attributes.  For example, if you have a `Trip`, you could display the km/miles of that trip with `Trip.distance` in the Aggregation unit.

Comment: Yes, it's displayed below because I think I can't change that:

http://gyazo.com/899771398dce4d6fed563f742831c00e.png?1351017763 

, then I cannot specific an action's title in my wall. 

Agree?

Comment: I agree.  The object will display as shown by the object-type settings, "preview" section: App Dashboard > Open Graph > [object-type] > Preview.  To see an accurate preview of an object click "Edit Preview Object" in the "Preview" section, then "Preview From URL", then paste in the URL of one of your og objects.